# Is there a way to store a variable while in a view in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, model-view-controller, view, model

As stated above. Is there a way to store a variable in a view in rails for later use without setting it in the controller function for that view?

ex.

```
<% bagel = @bagels.active_bagel %>
...
<%= bagel.delicious? %>
```

Comment: Are you asking about rendering the same bagel twice in a view or do you want the bagel to persist across requests?

Comment: @NateSHolland I would like the variable to be initialized and saved on each request for later use in the current request, no persistence necessary

Comment: what comes later? more views? if so... perhaps you should fetch/store the variable in your controller to be passed into the various views you will be using.

Comment: @TarynEast I know that it can be done in the controller, I'm asking if it's possible to do it in the view. The idea is that the beginning of my .html.erb sets a variable based on a condition, then farther down in the .html.erb, the variable gets used...

Comment: it's possible, but it's not considered good practice. If you can do it in the controller, then you probably should.
If you are inside of the *same* view template (instead of being in another template) then sure - go ahead and set variables (we do it all the time), but if you go to another template to use this variable... then it should be set in the calling scope, not be a magic variable that is used in multiple templates, if you see what I mean :)

Comment: made it into an answer... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are inside of the *same* view template (instead of being in another template) then sure - go ahead and set variables just as in your example. We do this all the time.

...but if you go to another template to use this variable... then it should be set in the calling scope, not be a magic variable that is used in multiple templates, if you see what I mean :)

it's possible to do it, but it's not considered good practice. If you can do it in the controller, then you probably should.

In your case... I don't think there should be a problem with you calling `active_bagel` more than once on the `@bagels` variable.

If you are trying to do this because you think it might plausibly be slow someday.... I'd recommend waiting until it is *actually* slow... then figuring out how to optimise for speed then. If it's for some other purpose... then tell us what that is and we'll figure out a better way.

Comment: Thanks for the info, is it normally done the way Antarr explained in his answer?

Comment: No there isn't a usual way, because usually we don't do it across templates.  Antarr's is a hacky way (though it does answer your question) - also it doesn't involve using it in later ruby - you'd be using javascript to pull it out again in later templates, which means it would be inaccessible to other ruby in other templates.

Comment: To clarify, I would not be using this variable in other templates, only the current rendering of the current template. Still looking for a way to do this.

Comment: as I said in my answer - if it's in the same template, then what you are doing right now is just fine :)

Comment: So what I posted in the example would work? even if the variable 'bagel' does not exist at the time of the call? I can initialize variables like this?

Comment: yes, you can initialise and use variables in templates - I do it all the time. They last for the scope of the template, and can be passed into child-templates. Just can't be passed across to sibling-templates without trickery

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieve by this

```
       #app/views/xyz/

      #1. make a hidden html input field
          <input type ="hidden" id = "you_id" value = "<%= yourvariable %>"

    #if u want to access that variable in every view write your code in app/helper/application_helper

    #otherwise write in the specific helper something this kind of code

           def yourvariable
            #your code
            return somthing which you want in view
            end

         and from that html tag access the value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

```
tag("div", class: :bagel, :data => {bagel_id: 3})
```

Then use [jQuery.data()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) to retrieve the value.